# Recovering VAIO laptops

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio

My new VAIO laptop Windows often chrashes (and dumps).

I decided to recover just the `C` drive with my recovery DVDs.  Can I just recover drive `C` without changing other partions?

Comment: Regardless of whether you have other partitions, you should be able to restore with the Windows (or maybe VAIO Care) restore disks. Just boot off the CD and make sure you select the partition you want to restore. What other partitions do you have? Another OS or a Data partition?

Comment: 4 partion that i save my music and movies and 2 partion for linux

Comment: Are you running GRUB? If you reinstall the Windows OS, your GRUB will be overwritten and you will have to reinstall GRUB. You'll have to do something like this: http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=reinstall+grub+after+windows+install&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would really depend on how those recovery DVD's are set up, but in all likelihood, the answer is a resolute no. I have never seen one that gave you that kind of granularity. They usually just start and go through the process without any question other than, "Do you really want to, you will lose all your data." If you do, have a backup.

If you can get a Windows 7 OEM DVD, you can install and select where it will install, leaving any additional partitions in place.

Since you say the laptop is new, but crashing a lot, that does not sound right to me. If you did not install something that is causing those crashes, I would actually suspect the hardware may have an issue.

Comment: Wouldn't the Vaio Care disk be better than a standard OEM DVD? It probably has all the drivers, etc., plus the windows recovery?

Comment: kalaracey, normally yes, but in this case, it would probably just format the entire disk, overwriting partitions he expressly did not want to touch.

Comment: @KCotreau : thanks for helping!

i find the problem! a zonealarm 32bit was the couse of blue screens!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a recovery disc, it's highly doubtful that you will be able to do just a partition. If you were to use an OEM disc and installed it, then it's possible.

You might can and I don't know if it would be legal or not in your case, but in my previous times, when my XP disc (OEM) got damaged, I was able to borrow a family's Disc, and used my own key which worked. But they have to be the same suite IE: XP Pro SP1 -> XP Pro SP1.